# Looking for event calendar with few advanced features

Tags: javascript, jquery

basically what I am looking for is a calendar for a room plan in a hotel management. 
I'll try to give an example of what I need the calendar to be able to do.

The column headings are days. Either a month or a week. And the rows are rooms (eg. room 101, conference room, etc.) When I create an event (book a room), say, from 12am on Monday to 11pm on Thursday the event has to go through Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday, but has to start in the middle of the Monday field and end almost at the end of the Thursday field to represent the starting times.

Something like this:

```
         | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday |
---------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+----------+--------|
Room 101 |    <-----Booked from 12am to 11pm-----> |        |          |        |
```

So yeah, do any of you know of a calendar that has this feature? Thank you all for reading and for help. Looking forward to your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/timeline.html) javascript library is great for making custom timelines, heavily scrollable, customizable and editable.

You can even add custom 'labels' to the units on the timeline.

Comment: Dwam, allright. Seems it has what I need and plenty more on top of that. Will probably take me few days to learn it and implement it, but still beats trying to write the thing myself. Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: @CreamWhippedAirplane You are right, it takes some time to implement in the most useful way, but it is definitely worth it. Good luck!